# How to display prometheus label, as value?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

I am using the windows node exporter, and it contains a label value of ‘version’ with the windows_os_info query. I am running grafana 7.2.1, and have tried various configurations I cannot get it to just show the ‘version’ . Any ideas?

[image: Current View]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try `sum by (version) (your_original_query_here)`.

Comment: Just gave that a try , no luck unfortunately. (updated screenshot in main question)

Comment: In retrospect, yes, `sum by (label)`shouldn't have changed a thing. But what do you expect for Grafana to display. Literally. Can you show what Prometheus Console returns?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be best using a table for this. I have tested this with a similar query of:

```
sum by (instance,version) (windows_os_info)
```

Then creating a table with the following options:

[Query options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETT00.png)

Then under the transform section select "Organize fields" and have it display only the instance and version.

You can of course play around with this so it displays as per your needs.

The end result looks something like:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcCwm.png)